# How to allow file downloads in Webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Does anyone know how to allow downloads in Webview (Android Studio)? I got PDF documents on website, but can't  download PDF documents in application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works perfect! :)